# Excel vba custom lookup function: fast when used manually, slow in macros

Tags: vba, excel

I had to write my own lookup function, but its performance differs dramatically depending whether or not I call it by hand on worksheet itself (through '=') or through macros. My macros does the following:

```
Function betterSearch(searchCell As Range, aCol As Range, bCol As Range)
        For Each cell In aCol
            If LCase(cell.Value) = LCase(searchCell.Value) Then
                    betterSearch = bCol.Cells(cell.row, 1)
                    Exit For
            End If
            betterSearch = "Not found"
        Next
End Function
```

So the macros opens `resultsWorkbook` and `dataWorkbook` and then performs a search of the four values in column A from `resultWorkbook` in `dataWorkbook` and returns corresponding data from some other column of `dataWorkbook`.

```
'...opening resultWorkbook and dataWorkbook
For aRow = 6 To 9
            resultWorkbook.Worksheets("B3").Cells(aRow, 125).Value = _
                betterSearch(resultWorkbook.Worksheets("B3").Cells(aRow, 1) _
                , dataWorkbook.Worksheets("page 1").Range("A:A") _
                , dataWorkbook.Worksheets("page 1").Range("Z:Z"))

             resultWorkbook.Worksheets("B3").Cells(aRow, 126).Value = _
                betterSearch(resultWorkbook.Worksheets("B3").Cells(aRow, 1) _
                , dataWorkbook.Worksheets("page 1").Range("A:A") _
                , dataWorkbook.Worksheets("page 1").Range("I:I"))
Next aRow
```

It's really slow - takes minutes for 1 file. But when I open that file manually and just type in the formula and hit Enter it calculates instantly.

What is wrong here? Where does this behaviour come from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be slow if it attempts to search through the entire columns A:A, I:I (1+ million cells)

Try updating your betterSearch to this:

```
Function betterSearch(searchCell As Range, aCol As Range, bCol As Range)
    Dim itm As String, col1 As Variant, col2 As Variant, r As Long

    With ActiveSheet
        col1 = .UsedRange.Columns(aCol.Column)
        col2 = .UsedRange.Columns(bCol.Column)
    End With

    betterSearch = "Not found"
    itm = LCase(searchCell.Value2)

    For r = 1 To UBound(col1)
        If Len(col1(r, 1)) > 0 Then
            If LCase(col1(r, 1)) = itm Then
                betterSearch = col2(r, 1)
                Exit Function
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Function
```